# No permission to delete / overwrite files in subfolders of ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am facing an problem with files that I create within my application in dedicated sub folders of *ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder*. I can create sub folders with *ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync()* and even place files in it. But as soon as I try to overwrite or delete files, I get an access violation exception. (Read Access is still possible)

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I looked up the UWP pages but most of the time they simply create a new folder and that's it.
My attempt to overwrite the file:

```
public async Task WriteFileAsync(string filename, Stream fileContent)
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var deepFolders = filename.Split('/');
    if (deepFolders != null)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<deepFolders.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(deepFolders[i]);
        }
        filename = deepFolders[deepFolders.Length - 1];
    }
    try
    {
        StorageFile oldFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        await oldFile.DeleteAsync();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) { }

    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

The first time it runs just fine, but as soon as the overwrite should take place, I get the exception.
Running the whole stuff without sub-folders works like charm.
The attempt to first read and delete the file resulted in the same exception already during the deletion.

Comment: What's the actual code you use? The two lines above are not correct. Also do you have the file open at the time you try to replace it?

Comment: I updated it with the whole save method to save a file into an existing folder hierarchy. It will not work if the folders do not exist, but adding this code can come later once I figured out the problem for the access violation.

Comment: Is it working now or not?

Comment: It does not work with the example above. It only works when I am not using any sub-folders but store everything directly in LocalFolder.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the method (where you save content to file)? Are you disposing streams? On which line exactly you get the exception? Can you provide a complete sample with the problem?

Comment: This is the complete method. The stream is disposed at the caller side and the error occurs when it tries to delete the old file (or if I remove this, when I tries to overwrite the file in the last line).